# How to get PHP array value in Javascript without JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have PHP array like this :

```
Array ( [1631196322] => 
                <div id="area_'.$randId.'">
                    <table id="table_'.$randId.'" contenteditable="true" '.$tableContent.'
                    </table>
                </div> 
        [16865437] => a16865437 );
```

I convert it into JSON :

```
{"1631196322" : "<div id="area_'.$randId.'">
                    <table id="table_'.$randId.'" contenteditable="true" '.$tableContent.'
                    </table>
                </div>",
"16865437" : "a16865437" }
```

Than I call Javascript function

```
<?php
$tables = json_decode($table);
foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
    echo '<button onclick="tampilisi('.$key.')">Tombo '.$key.'</button>';
}
?>
<div id='display'></div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tampilisi(isi){
        var txt = '<?php echo $table;?>';
 
        var data = JSON.parse(txt);
 
        datai = data[isi];
        $('#display').text(datai);
    }
</script>
```

I got error because the JSON containing HTML. If I change the JSON data into this :

```
{"1631196322" : "aaaaaaaaa",
    "16865437" : "a16865437" }
```

It has no problem, so I think I can't using JSON in this case. What solution do you thing that I must to do?

Comment: why would you want to display a table in such a convoluted manner? don't use javascript to determine what php values to display before the DOM loads, use PHP for that.

Comment: a couple of notes .. don't convert JSON by hand in PHP you can use `json_encode` encode instead. Where is `$randId` or `$tableContent` coming from in the JSON which you are trying to create?

Comment: Your conversion to JSON is invalid. How do you convert your array to json?

Comment: @bartholomew I have so complicated situation. The table is like static string that storage in array. So I have array contains HTML table on it

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal I just type here in stackoverflow manually, I convert PHP array using json_encode

Comment: "I just type here in stackoverflow manually" - don't do that; we need to see _the actual code that fails_, otherwise we're just debugging code that never existed. Specifically, you need to show us a [mcve] and the actual text of the error it gives you.

Comment: `var txt = '<?php echo $table;?>';`? Mixing php and javascript doesn't look correct in this instance - where are you deriving `$table` from at that point and is it to be the same for every instance of `tampilisi` being called?

Comment: as I said, if I change value of JSON from HTML  table into any string (for example : "aaaaa"), it will working

Comment: Sorry if I type Json format manually because I can't copy it. Browser will read HTML and display table

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your JSON and JavaScript string generator `var txt = '<?php echo $table;?>';`.

#### Incorrect JSON format

```
{"1631196322" : "<div id="area_'.$randId.'">
                    <table id="table_'.$randId.'" contenteditable="true" '.$tableContent.'
                    </table>
                </div>",
"16865437" : "a16865437" }
```

This format is incorrect because you cannot have " inside a string like this:

```
"This is first part of the string" and this is a second "
```

This is because a string starts and ends with " and it cannot contain itself unless it's escaped. To escape " inside JSON string you have to escape it with \ as follows:

```
"This is first part of the string\" and this is a second "
```

#### Incorrect JavaScript template

Line `var txt = '<?php echo $table;?>';` generates incorrect JavaScript string which cannot contain line breaks, e.g.:

```
var txt = 'This is
not a valid
string in JavaScript';
```

To have a valid JavaScript string with line breaks like this you have to use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as follows:

```
var txt = `This is
a valid
string in JavaScript`;
```

Comment: how to escape it? I'm I have to add \ before all " manually using PHP replace?

Comment: @DVCorps I don't know how you're generating the JSON string so I cannot help here. str_replace is definitely one of the solutions.

Comment: I just use json_encode($array) from controller toconvert it into JSON format

Comment: @DVCorps Then your JSON should already be correctly escaped. I assume you've pasted the JSON incorrectly. I assume your problem is the string templates then.

Comment: I can't pasted it because if I use echo, the browser will read HTML and display table

Answer (score 0):

I still using JSON but I convert HTML data into `base64` format